# How to prevent Ubuntu locking up when out of memory?

Tags: ram

I have a 16gb system and it's all too easy to accidentally lock it up and lose all the work by launching a Virtualbox machine before checking the available free ram.

How can I prevent Ubuntu 19.10 from locking up and falling over when it's out of memory?

Swappiness value is set to 60.

Comment: How much swap space is there?

Comment: htop reports 16gb swap.

Comment: How much memory have you assigned to the virtual machine you are trying to run? Include the output of `head -4 /proc/meminfo` command just before and after you launch your virtual machine **in your original post**.

Comment: Only 4GB, which seems reasonable for a 16GB system.

Comment: Normally it is enough with as much swap as RAM (even for hibernation). But it must be measured in the same units. RAM is usually measured in gibibytes (2"30 bytes) while swap might be measured in gigabytes (10^9 bytes) and 1 gibibyte = 1.074 gigabytes. It would probably be a good idea to have slightly more swap than RAM. Swappiness = 60 should be good enough. - Please notice that swapping is very slow, so the system might not be locked, only very very slow. The old (classic) advice was to have swap size = twice the RAM size, but I don't think it is reasonable, maybe 20 % more swap than RAM.

Comment: The system is not slow: it is locked. Neither mouse or keyboard controls are responding and the screen is not updating. It's not responding to input for minutes on end. That is not "slow".

Adding more ram I don't think will help if swapping is locking the system.

Comment: Well, according to my experience swapping is not locking a well configured Ubuntu system. But it may make it very very slow. You may have to wait longer than a few minutes. - I try to avoid that kind of swapping simply by monitoring the RAM used (I use `htop` like you do) and avoiding to start too many processes at the same time. - I agree that allocating 4GB for a virtual machine is reasonable for a 16GB system

Comment: RIght, this is exactly why I am asking the question - I should not have to monitor system resources in order for it not to lock up. I don't think this is an acceptable user experience, personally.

Comment: Let us hope that someone who knows more about the swapping process (than I do) can chip in and help you solve your problem :-)

Comment: Is swapping happening on the VM Guest, Host, or both? VM Guest swapping can be atrocious, since the swap must be virtualized.

Comment: I run vms all the time on my oldish 16gb system and they work fine. The only memory related lockup I've had was due to a bug in gvfs when connecting usb devices to a vm. You wouldn;t be doing that by any chance would you?

Comment: No USB devices connected, no!

The swapping is on the VM host.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Temporarily try setting the VM Guest to use 2G RAM, and set `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10` and see if things improve.